# Azul Zing installation configuration issue

Tags: java, azul-zulu, azul-zing

I recently installed Azul Zing "**zing-jdk1.8.0-16.01.2.0-2-x86_64**" on a private cloud in AWS. When I do "java -version OR java", I am getting following:

**Failed to reserve lower 2g address. error : 12**

My Java Home is set fine:

> echo $JAVA_HOME
>
> /opt/zing/zing-jdk1.8.0-16.01.2.0-2-x86_64

From the error it looks like its some configuration issue related to memory allocation. I am new to Azul Zing, can someone suggest me what could be the reason?

Answer (score 4):

Zing require lower 2g address for internal needs. When it can not allocate the address space it shows such message. Usually it happens when you are launching a JVM from C process and in C process you did some allocations in lower 2g. Or you are simply using a tiny server (or ZST pool) that does not fit requirements. You may need to adjust your ZST size to ensure there is at least 2g memory free on the linux side.

For more information you may need to contact Azul Customer Support (support@azul.com)`

Answer (score 1):

You can resolve this by running the command 'system-config-zing-memory'. You can take the default settings and ratios for the heap, or specify your own. Once you've done that, the VM will attempt to start with your configuration.